# Проблема с формой и JS

Tags: форма, html, javascript

Вот код

**JS:**

```
function one() {
  var nameOne = document.getElementsByName('One');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameOne.length; i++) {
    if (nameOne[i].type === 'checkbox' && nameOne[i].checked) {
      rezultatOne = 'Текст';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('rezultatOne').innerHTML = rezultatOne;
}
function two() {
  var nameTwo = document.getElementsByName('Two');
  for (var i = 0; i < nameTwo.length; i++) {
    if (nameTwo[i].type === 'checkbox' && nameTwo[i].checked) {
      rezultatTwo = 'Текст';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('rezultatTwo').innerHTML = rezultatTwo;
}
```

**HTML:**

Первый

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick='one()' name="one" >
<output id="rezultatOne"></output>
```

Второй

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick='two()' name="two"></br>
<output id="rezultatTwo"></output>
```

**Вот проблема**

При нажатии на первый чекбокс выводит текст, при нажатии на второй, текст не выводит, убираю контейнер формы текст выводится при обоих нажатиях.Если оставить любой из двух чекбоксов тогда работать будет даже в форме. А вдвоем не как как не хотят работать. В чем проблема?

Comment: Положите всё на jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

FF показывал ошибку "TypeError: one is not a function", когда имя элемента "one" и имя функции совпадали. Поэтому в примере функции названы f_one() и f_two()

http://jsfiddle.net/boris_U/zgr16679/

Answer (score -1):

У Вас в html `id="rezultaTtwo"`, а в js `document.getElementById('rezultatTwo')`.

Напишите `rezultatTwo` одинаково, и все ок должно быть.

Comment: Исправил то же самое

Comment: Мало того, это не единственное место, где регистр перепутан.